# The security token included in the request is invalid

Tags: amazon-web-services, credentials

I realize this error is likely something w/my credentials, but I have my credentials in both the ENV (exported from .bashrc) and in the ~/.aws/credentials file. I've checked they are both correct and the same value.

```
$ python describe_stream.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "describe_stream.py", line 5, in <module>
    response = kinesis.describe_stream('asdfTest')
  File "/Users/asdf/Work/kinesis_test/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/kinesis/layer1.py", line 247, in describe_stream
    body=json.dumps(params))
  File "/Users/asdf/Work/kinesis_test/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/kinesis/layer1.py", line 878, in make_request
    body=json_body)
boto.exception.JSONResponseError: JSONResponseError: 400 Bad Request
{u'message': u'The security token included in the request is invalid.', u'__type': u'UnrecognizedClientException'}

$ cat ~/.bashrc
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=AKIAXXXXXXXXX
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=qccXXXXXXXXXXXX

$ cat ~/.aws/credentials
[default]
aws_access_key_id=AKIAXXXXXXXXXX
aws_secret_access_key=qccXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Note, this just started happening today, the exact same credentials worked the past two days.

I'm getting this error on any AWS related command I try to execute, from Kinesis to S3.

Thanks

Comment: Post the actual error message.

Comment: Yeah sorry about that.

Comment: Haha, it's only my 8th day on the job! Not fired. hahaha

Comment: So, I had IT generate me new keys and it worked....